# Windows: How to Open an EXE, let it run, then trigger another script once it close.

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, exe

The Background.
So one of my teams has built a desktop application installer and all. It runs and will open up different processes depending on the function it happens to be using at the time.

The problem. 
When we open (We'll call it "Jim.exe") it runs smoothly. Different parts of Jim will open up additional Jim.exe's depending on which parts it's using. This directly is not the problem.

The problem is that not all of those additional processes close when you exit the application. This is admittedly an oversight in Development but the fellow who designed that process no longer works on the project.

Original Attempted Solution. 
I have been tasked with finding a way to close those rogue processes. I did get some assistance using VBS to search and destroy these processes. Using the below:

Kill.vbs:

```
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
     & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
     ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'Jim.exe'")
    For Each objProcess in colProcessList
     objProcess.Terminate()
    Next
```

However I could not find a way to attach it to a close event of any kind so I came up with a .bat to start the exe and contain it until it closes thus triggering the kill.vbs:

Box.bat (Box.exe)

```
    "C:\Program Files\Jim Folder\Jim.exe"

    Call "C:\Program Files\Jim Folder\Kill.vbs"
```

I converted the above .Bat into an exe of its own so the user can use the shortcut to this "Box.exe" to 1. open the actual exe. 2. wait for the application to close 3. trigger Kill.vbs.

Works perfect ! But I can't use it ... 
The Box.exe is immediately flagged by AV and eaten ... You can probably guess why.

My Question To You. 
Is there possibly another way of arranging this so AV does not eat my .Exe? Or a different way to script that will close rogue processes once the application is closed. I am sure there are multiple ways to resolve this problem but I am drawing a blank. It doesn't have to be a vbs or .bat necessarily any script or code will do if I can pick apart what makes it work.

The Goal. 
A way to kill Rogue processes not closed by the application.

p.s. I used Bat2Exe to convert Box.bat to Box.exe

I really hope this is clear enough to understand let me know if you need more information. Also it will be user facing so I can't have terminal windows opening when it is launched and I can't have AV quarantining it.

Comment: If the converted batch file works, why can't you simply use the batch file without converting it?

Comment: I was trying to avoid users clicking on a batch file on the desktop. I could fairly easily stop the terminal window opening up. It seems Webroot and Windows defender doesn't like the Batch file either. It flags it as something different but I can't really have users needing to allow their AV to let it go. Oddly enough it doesn't flag the .vbs at all .

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to sign the exe or register it somewhere so it doesn't get flagged but I haven't had much luck searching for that either. The exe is flagged as a trojan and the .bat is flagged as a .heur. I would have preferred it stay the way it is since it does work but I was denied on that front.

Comment: Good News! We were actually able to keep it as is. Signing the installer seems to have carried over to Box.exe preventing it from being eaten by AV

Comment: Please post the solution you found as an answer rather than a comment; so you can accept it, and the question does no longer appear open in the SO database...